# Interagindo com imagens

Tags: java, c#, .net, programação-estruturada

Fala galera.. sou novo na area, mais to procurando estudar bastante..
Comecei com java, ja dei fazer bastante "coisinhas", pequenos softwares de automação de empresas e talz..

porem, tava querendo fazer uma parada nova, e nao sei por onde fazer, segue o q é:

queria criar 1 programa, aonde meio que automatizasse um outro aplicativo externo, no caso 1 jogo, queria criar 1 bot, para 1 jogo, porem nao que injete algo nas Dlls, e sim, que fizesse analise de imagens
e de acordo com o que estivesse na imagem apresentada, ele tomasse alguma ação, no caso um jogo 2d, com imagens simples, sem muitas coisas...

Só que nao sei que Linguagem uso para fazer esse tipo de leitura da tela do jogo, e se tem alguma api q ajuda a fazer isso!

Alguem consegue me indicar algum caminho, pra começa a estudar?
fiquei meio perdido de por onde

Tentei um pouco com a classe ROBOT do java, porem o maximo q consegui foi 1 MACRO meio burro, ja q ele nao analisa a tela, antes de executar as funcões...

Vlw